# Permission denied when trying to deploy Flask app on AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I've created a Flask app and am trying to deploy it for testing on an EC2 machine using Flask's micro web framework (just for testing purposes). I'm serving the app on `host=0.0.0.0`  and `port=80` yet everytime I try and run the app it throws this error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on all ports` . The weird thing is when I use `app.run()` without any arguments meaning that it serves the app on the localhost address of the machine and the default port 5000, it runs without a problem. I have opened access to all incoming HTTP requests to port 80 in the AWS console. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 and 443 requires special permission. Try running your flask application with `sudo` in front of your command.

Example: `sudo python3 main.py`.

Comment: sudo works, but then i have to reinstall everything with sudo pip install. There must be a better solution